# I see empty list of disks using "az disk list". Created in AKS and working ok

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to follow this tutorial to backup a persistent volume in Azure AKS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv

I can see the volumes doing

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group MYRESOURCEGROUP --name  HIDDEN --subscription MYSUBSCRIPTION

kubectl get pv
```

(Both disk and file, managed-premium and standard storage classes)

but then I do:

```
az disk list --resource-group MYRESOURCEGROUP  --subscription MYSUBSCRIPTION
```

and I get an empty list, so I can't know the source full path to perform the snapshot.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that happens because AKS is creating a service resource group with AKS resources, it is called something like `MC_%AKS-name%_%AKS-resource-group-name%_%region%` (not configurable at the time of writing). you should list disks in that resource group to view those.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your az cli version.

I was getting this issue with az cli 2.0.75 returning an empty array for the disk list, with an AKS PV.

upgraded to az cli 2.9.1 and same command worked.